# How do you find a value in Visual Studio Debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some C# code, and somewhere in the many objects that are generated by the code, there is a string value `"my cool value"`. At one point in time during debugging,  I know that this string has been created, but I can't find it in any objects (by finding, I mean hover over an object with my mouse and explore the menus). Is there a search method for finding values in objects during runtime? I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Comment: If you have a loop through these objects, for example, you can try placing a conditional breakpoint, e.g. on the expression `object.Value == "My cool value"`.

Comment: You can set [Conditional Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce(v=vs.100).aspx) in your code, but it requires that you know where to look. If the string is located in a nested object, it may be difficult to capture the value in the breakpoint condition.

Comment: How do you know it is created, but don't know to what it is assigned?

Comment: Do you know the scope of that variable?

Comment: @monstertjie_za because it's a WebForms project, and I see the same value appear on screen every time I run a method. I want to find where this value comes from, and the first step would be actually finding this value in my code during debug.

Comment: @RashidJaved yes, it's in a large variable (lets call it X), that's inside a known method.

Comment: Can you not debug the project and step into the method until you find what line causes the string to be displayed on the screen, and work from there?

Comment: Well, that value can be returned as a string, without having to set any variable equal to it.  This can also be embedded in the page's Html. I will suggest you do a "Find" in your source code for that value, and try and see where it is being set.

Comment: Well in your web form, the value is being set to a label or a textbox, you can find the name of the label/textbox, trace it in your cs code by find usages, and set a break point to where it is being assigned the value, then you can trace it all the way back to the source.

Comment: Another way to start tracing this is to look for the string in your source code (just search across the whole project/solution, use Ctrl-Shift-F), then find it's uses (once again do a search, or if you have Resharper it's a context menu option).

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the variables in the "Autos" tab on debugging.

Explore the object and for example, if it is a label object. You can get the object's Text in "Name" Column and the value in "Value" Column. I will attach the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: He sees the value in the WebForm which is long after it was assigned in code behind, he wants to know where it is being assigned from. Please read the question better

Comment: Sorry. I thought it is for localApp C# code like WinForms and commented later without notifying the new comments.

Answer (score 0):

In these tabs Autos, Local etc. in Visual Studio 2022 there is a search option. I don't remember what it was like in older versions.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpoOO.png)